# Stop visitors from viewing my source code

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Visitors can right click the web page and select view source or they press ctrl+u or ctr+shft+i or ctrl+shft+j or f12 and they can view the web page source code.

i did not create this code. i only modified it to suit my needs. So credit goes to those out there that are true coders! Thank you! initially i had embedded my html code into an iframe. when a visitor right clicked on the page they got an option for viewing the page source or frame source. other functions were also available that allowed the viewing of the code. adding this code to my pages stopped visitors from easily viewing the code by using any of the above mentioned methods.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onload = function () {
       document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
       }, false);
       document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
           //document.onkeydown = function(e) {
           // "I" key
           if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 73) {
               disabledEvent(e);
           }
           // "J" key
           if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 74) {
               disabledEvent(e);
           }
           // "S" key + macOS
           if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? 
 e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
               disabledEvent(e);
           }
           // "U" key
           if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 85) {
               disabledEvent(e);
           }
           // "F12" key
           if (event.keyCode == 123) {
               disabledEvent(e);
           }
       }, false);
       function disabledEvent(e) {
           if (e.stopPropagation) {
               e.stopPropagation();
           } else if (window.event) {
               window.event.cancelBubble = true;
           }
           e.preventDefault();
           return false;
       }
   }
</script>
</head>

<body oncontextmenu="return false">
<body>
```

Comment: This won't work. Anyone can select the address bar (not the document body) and press control-U to view the source HTML - or, one could open the developer tools before loading the page, then view each network response. (this will show loaded code even if it isn't rendered in the initial HTML)

Comment: (also, there is no question here - SO is a question-and-answer site. maybe you meant to pose the *question* in the question body, and then self-answer it?)

Comment: @CertainPerformance Or, directly `curl` or append "view-source:" in front of the URL in some browsers.

Comment: https://obfuscator.io/

Comment: You will not be able to stop users from looking at your client side (front end) code. If there is confidential information like api-keys, an email address, etc that you want to hide, you need a server side to your application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments everyone! I'm still learning. And yes, it is correct that this usually isn't a good idea to do to a page and yes there will be some who know all the different ways one can access the source code of a page. However, there will be many who only know of a couple ways to get there and many more who dont know how to at all. So I posted the previous before i found some issues with it. so i re-worked the script and now it does what i wanted. Im posting in the hopes that it helps someone. Goal: visitors will be unable to  right-click the "page" or use ctrl+u, ctrl+shft+i, ctrl+shft+j or f12 to view options AND will be unable to use the browser back button. NOTE: web page is embedded within an iframe. Again, thanks to you coders and the info that you post! it's helping me learn!

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function changeHashOnLoad() {
window.location.href += "#";
setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50"); 
}
function changeHashAgain() {
window.location.href += "1";
}
var storedHash = window.location.hash;
window.setInterval(function () {
if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
window.location.hash = storedHash;
}
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
}, false);
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
//document.onkeydown = function(e) {
// "I" key
if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 73) {
disabledEvent(e);
}
// "J" key
if (e.ctrlKey && e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 74) {
disabledEvent(e);
}
// "S" key + macOS
if (e.keyCode == 83 && (navigator.platform.match("Mac") ? 
e.metaKey : e.ctrlKey)) {
disabledEvent(e);
}
// "U" key
if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 85) {
disabledEvent(e);
}
// "F12" key
if (event.keyCode == 123) {
disabledEvent(e);
}
}, false);
function disabledEvent(e) {
if (e.stopPropagation) {
e.stopPropagation();
} else if (window.event) {
window.event.cancelBubble = true;
}
e.preventDefault();
return false;
}
}, 50);
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="changeHashOnLoad(); ">
```

Comment: also, earlier in my posts i mention that my pages are embedded inside an iframe, applying the script to the iframe page also has same effect as applying script to page AND if a visitor knows how to use the address bar to reach ctrl+u they only see the code for the iframe page and not the code for the web page. the visitor would need to know that they can do ctrl+shft+i or j in the address window and how to drill down through the dev tools to actually reach the code of the web page. this script inconjunction with a web page embedded iframe page  will stop people from viewing the web page code.